# How to use jquery error(red) icons

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I have a span like this

```
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-close"></span>
```

which gives display a close icon of color same as the theme color.

But want to use the red icons which are available for the error.
Which jquery class should I use for that.

I found a class in Jquery css

```
.ui-state-error .ui-icon, .ui-state-error-text .ui-icon 
{background-image: url(images/ui-icons_cd0a0a_256x240.png); }
```

this image is the image which contains jquery red icons .
But I cant use it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The span's class only determines the icon.

Set the "ui-state-error" on its parent to change the icon's color to red.

Check the icon example here: http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/ (the bottom of the right sidebar).

Comment: Also, if you just want the red icon and not the red border use class `ui-state-error-text` instead of `ui-state-error` on the parent element

Answer (score 2):

When trying to use such icons before text, I got line break problems and a bad alignment between the icon and the text.

To avoid the icon to add a line break, use

```
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-name" style="display: inline-block;"></span>
```

To get a better alignment for the text, use the following

```
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-name" style="display: inline-block;"></span>
<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden;">Your text</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

If You want just icon with other color, not whole box as is the example here:
http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/, in bottom right conner

add this to anywhere in Your .css file:

```
.ui-icon-red { width: 16px; height: 16px; background-image: url(images/ui-icons_red_256x240.png); }
```

The name and path of the file are depend of the color what You wanted.

And in html:

```
<div class="ui-icon-red ui-icon-circle-zoomin">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert"></span>
```

should do it.

Edited because I think I now found the right class.

Comment: I tried your answer but it gives a red square border around the icon. But I want the icon to be red. Straightly I want to use the background-image: url(images/ui-icons_cd0a0a_256x240.png); which is already defined in the class I wrote above.

Comment: Sory It changing the icon nopt the color

Answer (score 0):

Apply ***ui-state-error*** to the layer containing the icon(s) and remove the default background and border:

CSS:

```
.error-state-icon.ui-state-error {
    border:none;
    background:none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="ui-state-error error-state-icon">
<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-info'></span>
</div>
```

**[Demo >>](http://jsfiddle.net/portashqipe/5h3dcdjp/)**